# Is their a better more efficient way to write this jQuery script?

Tags: jquery

I feel like my script is really redundant and could probably be written way better. I would be very appreciative if some one can give me some tips or thoughts on how to better implement this.
Basically a really simple slideshow.

```
 $('.projectview .designinfo').hide();
 $('.projectview .buildinfo').hide();
 $('.projectview .launchinfo').hide();
 $('.projectview .growinfo').hide();


 $('.thumbs ul li.plan').bind('click',
   function() {
       $('.projectview .designinfo, .projectview .buildinfo, .projectview .launchinfo, .projectview .growinfo').fadeOut();
       $('.projectview .planinfo').fadeIn();
   });
 $('.thumbs ul li.design').bind('click',
   function() {
       $('.projectview .planinfo, .projectview .buildinfo, .projectview .launchinfo, .projectview .growinfo').fadeOut();
       $('.projectview .designinfo').fadeIn();
   });
 $('.thumbs ul li.build').bind('click',
   function() {
       $('.projectview .planinfo, .projectview .designinfo, .projectview .launchinfo, .projectview .growinfo').fadeOut();
       $('.projectview .buildinfo').fadeIn();
   });
 $('.thumbs ul li.launch').bind('click',
   function() {
       $('.projectview .planinfo, .projectview .designinfo, .projectview .buildinfo, .projectview .growinfo').fadeOut();
       $('.projectview .launchinfo').fadeIn();
   });
 $('.thumbs ul li.grow').bind('click',
   function() {
       $('.projectview .planinfo, .projectview .designinfo, .projectview .buildinfo, .projectview .launchinfo').fadeOut();
       $('.projectview .growinfo').fadeIn();
   });
```

Here is the html

```
<section class="thumbs">
        <ul>
          <li class="plan">
            <img src="images/new/plan.jpg" alt="plan" class="serviceicon">
          </li>
          <li class="design">
            <img src="images/new/design.jpg" alt="design" class="serviceicon">
          </li>
          <li class="build">
            <img src="images/new/build.jpg" alt="build" class="serviceicon">
          </li>
          <li class="launch">
            <img src="images/new/launch.jpg" alt="launch" class="serviceicon">
          </li>
          <li class="grow">
            <img src="images/new/grow.jpg" alt="grow" class="serviceicon">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section class="projectview">
        <section class="planinfo"><img src="images/new/planinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="planinfo"></section>
        <section class="designinfo"><img src="images/new/designinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="designinfo"></section>
        <section class="buildinfo"><img src="images/new/buildinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="buildinfo"></section>
        <section class="launchinfo"><img src="images/new/launchinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="launchinfo"></section>
        <section class="growinfo"><img src="images/new/growinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="growinfo"></section>
      </section>
```

Comment: Should be migrated over to "code review" SE site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
$('.projectview').children().hide();
$('.projectview').children(".planinfo").show();

$('.thumbs ul li').click(function(){
    var thumb = $(this).attr('class');
    var partner = $('.' + thumb + 'info');
    $('.projectview').children().fadeOut();
    partner.fadeIn();
});
```

I haven't tested this yet, but it should work...

***Updated with fading tabs***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.thumbs ul li').css('opacity', '.5');
    $('.thumbs ul li:first-child').addClass('current');

    $('.projectview').children().hide();
    $('.projectview').children(".planinfo").show();

    $('.thumbs ul li').click(function(){

        // Show info
        var thumb = $(this).attr('class');
        var partner = $('.' + thumb + 'info');
        $('.projectview').children().fadeOut();
        partner.fadeIn();

        // Tab opacity
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

    });

});
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbs ul li {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 70px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity:.5;
}
    .thumbs ul li.current {
        opacity:1 !important;
    }
```

Comment: If you could provide a jsFiddle, we could test it out with some images to ensure the desired effect is achieved. Let me know if this works...

Comment: I updated this to show the `.planinfo` element after the others are hidden.

Comment: Hey Derek, i tried your code and it did not work. none of the divs with a class of project view showed up and nothing happens when i click on any of the .thumb ul li's. Am i missing something?

Comment: Just a thought would you know how to make the current thumb link opacity at 100% when you click on it and make all the others opacity= 40%? Again i wrote it up and it works it just seems to be the long way around it. Thank for you help again btw.

Comment: Just asecond, I'll put in images of my own. Sorry, I did this off the top of my head with a semi-clear idea of what you were asking.

Comment: No rush, thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: You're welcome. I'm workin on a netbook today, so it's takin a bit...

Comment: This is what i am trying to accomplish https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6swaQPDkGog, i just hate the way i went about writing the script knowing that their is a much cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle with what you have so I can make sure everything works properly? (With your CSS)

Comment: Yeah i'll do that right now

Comment: If you aren't too far along in your code, I would suggest using jQuery UI Tabs... http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ This is what I start with, then add the fading effects or whatever to them.

Comment: Here is my jsFiddle account http://jsfiddle.net/travis5567/vAzSn/

Comment: Oh wow, i should of used that and i probably will. I am using the jQuery ui anyways. I am still new to the jQuery ui so i don't remember all the things you can do with it yet off the top of my head. thanks

Comment: Check it out... http://jsfiddle.net/vAzSn/5/

Comment: All I did was change the `.thumb ul li` opacity to .5, then create a class of `.current` (that has an opacity of 1). Then, added the current class to whatever tab you select...(and remove it from whatever is currently the `.current`.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/vAzSn/7 <--- fixed the extra bracket in the CSS. Let me know if there is anything else you need bud... Also, made the .show() .planinfo use a better selector (so you don't have to specify the class name...

Comment: Thank you so much. this is perfect, plus i learned some new things as well.

Comment: Hey Derek, Came across a bug in the script you gave me. If i try clicking on the same thumb link twice it will not display an image. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

```
//hide all the choices
$('.projectview').children().hide();

$('.thumbs ul li').on('click', function(){
    $('.projectview').children().hide();
    $('.projectview').find('[class^='+this.className+']').show();
});
```

[Visualizing it](http://jsfiddle.net/UagYT/)

Comment: Couldn't you also just write `this.className` instead of `$(this).prop('class')`?

Comment: You could, but you also can't chain it and I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

And another solution:

```
<section class="thumbs">
  <ul>
    <li class="plan" data-alias="plan">
      <img src="images/new/plan.jpg" alt="plan" class="serviceicon">
    </li>
    <li class="design" data-alias="design">
      <img src="images/new/design.jpg" alt="design" class="serviceicon">
    </li>
    <li class="build" data-alias="build">
      <img src="images/new/build.jpg" alt="build" class="serviceicon">
    </li>
    <li class="launch" data-alias="launch">
      <img src="images/new/launch.jpg" alt="launch" class="serviceicon">
    </li>
    <li class="grow" data-alias="grow">
      <img src="images/new/grow.jpg" alt="grow" class="serviceicon">
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section class="projectview">
  <section class="planinfo" data-ref="plan"><img src="images/new/planinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="planinfo"></section>
  <section class="designinfo" data-ref="design"><img src="images/new/designinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="designinfo"></section>
  <section class="buildinfo" data-ref="build"><img src="images/new/buildinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="buildinfo"></section>
  <section class="launchinfo" data-ref="launch"><img src="images/new/launchinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="launchinfo"></section>
  <section class="growinfo" data-ref="grow"><img src="images/new/growinfo.jpg" alt="blog" class="growinfo"></section>
</section>


<script>
var $infos = $('> section', '.projectview');
$infos.hide();

$('li', '.thumbs').on('click', function() {
   var selector = '[data-ref="'+$(this).data('alias')+'"]';
   $infos.not(selector).fadeOut();
   $infos.filter(selector).fadeIn();
});
</script>
```